# Find-VBRViEntity returning no entities in veeam

Tags: powershell, veeam

I am new to Veeam backup and I have a small issue.
`Get-VBRServer -Name "maryland"` successfully returns a host. Running `Find-VBRViEntity` on this, however, no vm is returned. Any ideas why?

Comment: Are there any results if you pipe directly from `Get-VBRServer`? Like this: `Get-VBRServer -Name "maryland" | Find-VBRViEntity`. What are you trying to accomplish exactly, anyway?

Comment: No result even if i pipe directly

Comment: How about with the `-Server` parameter? You may want to try pointing it at vCenter. `Find-VBRViEntity -Server 10.1.1.1`. Trying by IP may help, too.

Comment: Still nothing is returned.

Comment: How about not specifying anything? Any results with simply `Find-VBRViEntity`? Might be worth a support case with Veeam if you still get no results and are confident the snapin is loaded correctly, they give excellent support.

Comment: None still. Just a question do I have to be using a `VMware vSphere` for this to work??

Comment: Not sure. Assumed you are using VMware - are you using Hyper-V?

Comment: No. I am using a normal windows 2016 server